# Add div container between text using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to add a `<div>` container in place of a check box. But the `<div>` container takes up the entire line. I tried all sorts of "floats" but none worked.

here is my css code:

```
.checkbox{
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With The inline div will not occupy the line

use this

```
.checkbox{
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    display:inline;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Style it with this:  `.inline {display: inline}`

Answer (score 0):

Use inline tag i.e.

```
inline { display : inline}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline is doing the trick, but you are really just avoiding the problem. You could have just set a width on the div and the label or whatever and floated them. By default block-level elements are 100% width. At some point, you are going to want to have some of the options that being display block allows - and inline doesn't. And you will probably also want to have some of the options that inline elements have, like vertical alignment. I suggest trying `inline-block` - I've been getting tons of use out of it. Give hit a spin:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/J6gjX/)

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check-box-01" />

<div class="check-box-replacement"></div> 

<label class="check-box-label" for="check-box-01">
    Label for this checkbox
</label>
```

### CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.check-box-replacement {
    width: 2em;
    height: 10em; /* just to prove a point */
    background-color: red;
}

.check-box-replacement, .check-box-label  {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```